# Retrieve Storage and Programs Memory on .NET Compact Framework 2 and WM5

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0

I've been looking for quite a while already and still couldn't find a solution for this.
All I need is to retrieve the memory levels and percentage of use.
OpenNETCF has a MemoryManagement class, which seems to encapsulates a data structure returned through a P/Invoke or something like that, and it gives me the TotalPhysicalMemory, TotalVirtualMemory, AvailablePhisicalMemory and such, but those do not directly relate to Storage and Programs, nor could I find a way to "convert" these attributes to those I need.

Has anyone there already done this? It must be easy, I just need the very same values available on Settings > System > Memory.

Thanks in advance!

edit: I'm already being able to retrieve Available and total Storage memory through the GetDiskFreeSpaceEx P/Invoke. Since Storage and Programs memory seem to rely into the same hardware, maybe it's just a case of finding out what path to pass as the method's first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [MemoryManagement class](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/11c937be-3ae0-6ac0-8d70-c3fd16aee5d0.htm), not the DeviceManagement class.  SystemStorageMemory and SystemProgramMemory are likely the properties you're after.

**EDIT 1**
For storage space, you'd use the [DriveInfo](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/930b0200-63bd-94a1-b0da-6a756c748aa7.htm) class, initialized to the device root ("\").

Comment: I already had a look into it, seems nice, but I'd still need to find out how much of those values is "free memory", since that's the most important in this case.

Comment: Then the AvailablePhysical is the Property you would look at.  That's the value returned from the GlobalMemoryStatus API.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! I ended up by getting storage via GetDiskFreeSpaceEx and programs using OpenNETCF's MemoryManagement MemoryLoad and SystemProgramMemory.